# porque no puedo sumar en python

Tags: python

alguien sabe por que no suma el problema esta en la linea 10 donde dice celdas +=1

```
 desde pynput import mouse import pyautogui from time import sleep

celdas = 0

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed): si se presiona: celdas = 0 ff = (str(button)+" pressed") print(str(button)+" pressed") celdas +=1 print(celdas) if celdas == 4: print("Ya va a ejecutarse") sleep(2) pyautogui.click() celdas = 0 print(celdas)

imprimir (celdas)

con mouse.Listener( on_click=on_click ) como oyente: listener.join()
```

lo que quiero hacer es un autoclick, que cuando yo precione 4 click python me ayuda a dar mas click. ha gradeceria si respondieran pero gracio igual por leer todo esto

Comment: El formato de tu código hace difícil que otros puedan replicar tu error (python es sensible a la indentación). Ahora que tu bloque de código tiene formato, podrías [edit] y poner el código formateado como tú lo tienes en tu ambiente de desarrollo, por favor?

Comment: Buen día, ¿Puedes agregar más detalles al error que tienes? ¿Qué sucede en lugar de sumar? ¿Aparece un error? Tal como está redactada tu pregunta no se entiende cual es el problema

Comment: No tengo idea de python, pero ¿puede ser que se hayan traducido palabras clave en ese códido sin ton ni son?  Veo un **desde**, un **si se presiona**, **imprimir**, **con**, **como oyente**... ¿eso es normal?  Lo pregunto desde mi más absoluta ignorancia, perdon si no procede.